# Resizing window which is created using window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, resize, window

I have a window which opens when the user clicks a link.

```
echo "<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"javascript:window.open('https://domain.com/page.php', 'windowName'); \" >Open Window</a>";
```

When this link is clicked, the page, **page.php** will be opened. Now I want to resize the window by providing height, width, top and left parameters. I know it is possible by sending them as third parameter of `window.open` function. But I want to do it in **page.php** file using jquery/javascript. I tried with the following code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
     alert("here");
      $(window).css({
        top: <?php echo $top;?>,
        left: <?php echo $bottom;?>
      });
    });
});
```

But when the **page.php** opens, it is not alerting anything also it is not getting resized. What I'm doing wrong? Can anyone please help me to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

On any page, when you bind a resize() event, it will be only get triggered on resizing the window.

You should try something like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
       windowResize(); // Triggered when window resized
    });
    windowResize(); // Triggered when page loaded
 });
 function windowResize() {
    alert("here");
    $(window).css({
       top: <?php echo $top;?>,
       left: <?php echo $bottom;?>
    });
 }
```

Comment: @Krunal..Now alert is coming but it is not resizing the window.

Comment: I have an alert coming in both cases. Please check in your code first, something may have conflicting with resize() event.

Comment: Alert is coming inside `windowResize()`.. But `$(window).css()` is not working ie, resizing of window is not happening.

Comment: It won't work. Because you are trying to resize the dimensions of the window, that is not possible. If you still want to resize, then take a container <div> and apply dimensions to that particular container.

Comment: @Jenz: You are not getting my point. If you trying to resize the browser with JavaScript then it is not possible. You need to try an alternate way to do this. But as far as I know, there is no front end technology which can do this.